# Get a PHP Variable From the Bottm to the Top

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am not sure how to do this. From the answer I've found on here, I think it's possible using jquery/ajax maybe. I need to get the value of my variable $i and echo it at the top, but it has to go through my logic to get to the value. Here is my code:

```
echo "<div id='records'><h1 align='center'>Today's Transfers (" . $i . ") </h1>
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr>
<th>Customer Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Disposition</th><th>User</th><th>Date Called</th>
</tr>
";

$i=0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vicidial_closer_log WHERE DATE(call_date) = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY call_date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $i++;
        $phone_number = $row['phone_number'];
        $lead_id = $row['lead_id'];
        $disposition = $row['status'];
        ...then echo those variable in my columns and rows...
    }
echo "</table> </div>";
echo $i;
```

Maybe there is another way to write my code so the logic comes before I output everything? Not sure how to do that though since I'm using a mysql query.

Comment: this is why we separate the code from the output, you can run ALL your code then deal with its output\presentation

Comment: use mysqli_num_rows to get the total number of records and move your echo after your query

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows($result)` can evaluate how many rows in your result.

Comment: `require('timemachine.php'); send_back_in_time($i, -50);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the number of rows from the result set and display those where the `i` is, since it is essentially the same thing.

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Move your code above the echo statement:

```
$i=0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vicidial_closer_log WHERE DATE(call_date) = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY call_date DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
```

and add

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<div id='records'><h1 align='center'>Today's Transfers (" . $num_rows . ") </h1>
```

and use the rest of your code as before .. Might think about removing `i` if you don't need it for something else.

Answer (score 0):

If $i is the total number of returned results, you could do:

```
echo mysqli_num_rows($result)
```

... and have your query executed at the top of the page.

This would ideally be all in a model and being set in a view by a controller however. That way you're separating the presentation from the functional logic.

I suggest you have a read about MVC:

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can just move the `echo` above your logic. But the best to do is to separate logic from presentation. You can create a class to handle this or maybe just another file, it depends on your needs.

```
$i=0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vicidial_closer_log WHERE DATE(call_date) = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY call_date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $i++;
        $phone_number = $row['phone_number'];
        $lead_id = $row['lead_id'];
        $disposition = $row['status'];


echo "<div id='records'><h1 align='center'>Today's Transfers (" . $i . ") </h1>
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr>
<th>Customer Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Disposition</th><th>User</th><th>Date Called</th>
</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your computations *first*, then display your data.

Horribly mangled example code:

```
$count = 0;
$output = '';
$res = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM...");

while( $row = mysql_fetch($res) ) {
  $output .= "<tr><td>..." . $row['somevar'] . "</td></tr>";
  $count++;
}

echo "<h1>Yadda yadda $count</h1>";
echo "<table>";
echo $output
echo "</table>";
```